# Simplifying Trig Identities

Tags: trigonometry

I feel like this problem is simple, but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

$$\dfrac{1}{sin^2(x)}+ \dfrac{sec^2(x)}{tan^2(x)}$$

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{1}{\sin^2(x)}+\dfrac{\sec^2(x)}{\tan^2(x)}&=\dfrac{1}{\sin^2(x)}+\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(x)}}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sin^2(x)}+\dfrac{1}{\sin^2(x)}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{\sin^2(x)}\end{align}$$
You can keep going like this.  So some more equalities are:
$$\dfrac{2}{\sin^2(x)}=2\csc^2(x)=2+2\cot^2(x)$$

Comment: Thanks, the book actually had the answer as $2csc^2(x)$, which is what I think you meant on the bottom there, instead of secant.

Comment: You are correct. I mistyped, I will fix it now.